# Need to change the default timeout of robotframework script

Tags: python-3.x, timeout, robotframework

I am using keyword 'Wait Until Element Is Visible' but need to change the default timeout from 5s to 10s.

Wait Until Element Is Visible | Locator|  10

Getting error:
Element ' Locator ' not visible after 5 seconds.

Comment: Are you using SeleniumLibrary? I can't reproduce your problem. When I change the value to 10, the keyword waits for 10 seconds as documented.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It is working as expected when I use "Wait Until Element Is Visible | Locator| timeout=10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the timeout, used:

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible | Locator| timeout=10
```